# Youtube API access is granted but I still have Invalid Credentials error

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-api, youtube-api, access-token

Trying to test search functions of the YoutubeAPI, but getting this
[image]

Could it be because of my channel(which is binded to my gmail account, which I currently using in console.developers.google) was banned?

UPD:
Created new account, situation still the same

Well, what I've have done here:

1. created porject in `console.developers.google`
2. activated youtube data api(choosed app or somth like this, not the
   js one), downloaded json, which looks like that

[image]

3. First I call the `Authorize` method (new page shows, asking permission, where I just clicking `allow` button, and everything seems like ok),  but then I trying to use `Search`
   and I get 401 error

heres the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication3.Services.ServiceAuthoriaztion.Impl
{
    using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Threading;
    using Google.Apis;
    using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
    using Google.Apis.Services;
    using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
    using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;


    public class Youtube : ICustomService
    {
        private static YouTubeService _currentYouTubeService;

        public void Authorize()
        {
            UserCredential userCreds;
           ;
            var filePath = string.Format("{0}{1}",AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"App_Data\client_id.json");
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                userCreds = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] {YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly},
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore("YouTubeData")
                    ).Result;
            }

            _currentYouTubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = userCreds,
                ApplicationName = "yttest"
            });

            SerachTest();

        }

        private void SerachTest()
        {
            var searchListRequest = _currentYouTubeService.Search.List("snippet");
            searchListRequest.Q = "Google"; // Replace with your search term.
            searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;

            // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
            var searchListResponse = searchListRequest.Execute();

            var asa = new List<string>();

        }
    }
}
```

UPD2:
Tried other type of app - not helped either. 
JSON file looks like that
[image]

Comment: The account using google developer console has no relation to the account used in OAuth2.    Is it popping up with the webpage to authenticate the application? were are you getting the 401?

Comment: @DaImTo yeah, I've got the new page shortly after creating new `YouTubeService`. Everthing seems like okay, but when I try to use `serach` I've got this 401 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I decided start everything from scratch, so, I don't know what exactly helped me but here's a simple instructions about how I made it work. And also, here's the proof :)
[image]

So, first I created new project, set name of it `DanilTestApp`.

Second, turned on `YouTube Data API` there.

When I was creating new credentials, choosed `OAuth Client ID` and then, as a type, choosed `Other`.

After it was ready I just downloaded JSON.

Then in my code I decide to add refreshing token functionality, so now it looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication3.Services.ServiceAuthoriaztion.Impl
{
    using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Threading;
    using Google.Apis;
    using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
    using Google.Apis.Services;
    using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
    using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;


    public class Youtube : ICustomService
    {
        private static YouTubeService _currentYouTubeService;

        public void Authorize()
        {
            UserCredential userCreds; 
            var filePath = string.Format("{0}{1}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @ "App_Data\client_id.json");
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                userCreds = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                 GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                 new[] {
          YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly
                 },
                 "user",
                 CancellationToken.None,
                 new FileDataStore("YouTubeData")
                ).Result;
            }

            RefreshToken(userCreds);

            _currentYouTubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = userCreds,
                ApplicationName = "DanilTestApp"
            });

            SerachTest();

        }

        private void SerachTest()
        {
            var searchListRequest = _currentYouTubeService.Search.List("snippet");
            searchListRequest.Q = "Google"; // Replace with your search term.
            searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;

            // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
            var searchListResponse = searchListRequest.Execute();

            var asa = new List<string>();

        }
        //might not work, but something like this, got working code at home, office right now
        private void UpdateTokenIfExpired(UserCredential credential)
        {
           if (credential.Token.IsExpired(credential.Flow.Clock))
           {

               Console.WriteLine("The access token has expired, refreshing it");
               if (credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("The access token is now refreshed");
               }
               else
               {
                   throw new Exception("refresh token failed");
               }

           }
       }

    }
}
```