# Calling Google APIs with service account c#

Tags: c#, youtube-data-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

I am facing the following problem: I have created a google service account and now I am trying make an authorized API call using c# to Google API and YouTube Data API. Here is my sample code:

```
string filePath = @"~\my-path\Default-GASvcAcct-508d097b0bff.json"

using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    googleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
}

if (googleCredential.IsCreateScopedRequired)
{
    googleCredential.CreateScoped(
        new string[] 
        {
            YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly,
            YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload,
            YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube,
            YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl,
            YouTubeService.Scope.Youtubepartner,
            YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubepartnerChannelAudit
        });
}

YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = googleCredential,
});

service.Videos.List()
```

The code builds successfully but when I start the program, I get the following error message:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'BouncyCastle.Crypto, Version=1.7.4137.9688, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=a4292a325f69b123' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.'

Does somebody know how to fix this error and also, is it possible to make request to YouTube Data API with service account credentials?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of .NET do you use?

Comment: And which version of the NuGet packages are you using? Note that you're ignoring the return value of `CreateScoped`, too - you should have `googleCredential = googleCredential.CreateScoped(...)`

Comment: check this it might be help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132531/list-youtube-videos-using-c-sharp-and-google-apis-youtube-v3

Comment: @Baruch in this project I am using .NET 4.5 - do you think the version of .NET could be the reason for this error? The exception has been thrown in the using statement.

Comment: @MangeshAuti the problem is not implementing the listing videos functionality but the authorization at all.

Comment: @RosenPetrov I am not saying it is a similar question, just check how they created user credentials of Google to access youtube

Comment: @RosenPetrov Please edit your question to include the information about `.NET 4.5`

Comment: @JonSkeet After updating Google.Apis.Auth and Google.Apis.YouTube.v3 NuGet packages and changing the code as you suggested it worked. Thanks!
But now I get the following error:
Google.GoogleApiException: 'Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project XXX before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=XXX then retry...

Comment: And did you then follow the advice in the error message, making sure you enabled it for the exact project specified in the message?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

According to Jhon Skeet's comment, if you update the Google API nuget's you will no longer be dependent on BouncyCastle.Crypto nuget, so this is also an option.

**Original answer:**

I can not prove unequivocally, but it seems that nuget `BouncyCastle.Crypto` is not suitable for `.NET 4.0`.

You can see that there is a [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable.BouncyCastle/) trying to make the portability.

And I also think there is a **pre-release** version that should be compatible with `.NET 4.0`:

[image: Nuget Package browser]

Comment: We stopped using BouncyCastle in the Google API libraries in December 2016. The best solution here is to use a recent version, not to try to get BouncyCastle working.